# How to call me function in laravel based jwt , Its giving 401 error when hit from my react application?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-authentication, laravel-jwt

Below is my auth controller and api routes file
login function is working well no issue in that but getting issue on me() function or /me post route please help me to solve it out.

**AuthController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use JWTAuth;
use JWTFactory;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Ok Bro !'], 200);
    }    
    
    public function login(Request $request)
    { 
         $password= bcrypt($request->password);
         $credentials1=[
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$password
         ];
       $credentials = request(['email',   'password',]);  
          if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Userid Or Password'], 200);
        } 

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        
       //return $credentials1;  // print_r($credentials);

       //$2y$10$yxnc9WKUM3fw4BlDOjJWM.8SYuLnWdEoRgrM4Nc\/iQspi2cAE8E5K
       //$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
       //  $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);

 ///return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
 
          return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user'=>auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Below is   api routes file
login function is working well no issue in that but getting issue on me() function or /me post route please help me to solve it out.

**Api Route**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
 
 
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
 
 

 
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login'); 
 

Route::group(['middleware'=>'api'],function(){
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
});
```

**Result on Post Request in console**
Issue i am getting on page from post request in react

[image]

Comment: Are you sending the jwt token in the authorisation header when calling that route?

Comment: I tried this way the issue is same

Comment: const getUser=()=>{
   axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/me', {
    headers: {
        'authorization': token,
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
   })

Comment: It should be `'authorization': 'Bearer [token]'` replacing `[token]` with your actual token.

Comment: Thanks it get solved by adding authorization as key and Bear token as value in headers array in post request . thanks Again